# Wix toolset Multiple Instances Installation

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

Some months ago I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540670/installing-multiple-instances-of-an-application-with-wix-toolset) about multiple installation, and I strictly followed the [example](http://sklyarenko.net/blog/2011/09/14/revisited-multiple-instance/) suggested me. 
It worked very fine, but I try to remove the default Instance.
When I type

```
   msiexec /x MyInstaller.msi
```

my App is "logically" removed, but **no folders and no files are deleted** on my machine!

Here is the code:

```
 <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Component Id="comp_67F76B3C_8D92_4DCF_8C51_42E51502C4A3" Guid="28C71156-F612-49ED-A4E9-0CB598AA84AB" MultiInstance="yes">
    <CreateFolder/>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="comp_AA102B27_0657_498D_9CD5_683C4F33B5E2" Guid="0F601C97-CDFF-4614-A608-B42253240E2C">
    <File Id="_C72F9A1F_AF4A_47A3_928C_238643ABA5D4" Name="CrashReportManager.exe" Source="..\workspace\Release\CrashReportManager.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="comp_442142FD_D0B8_410C_8904_E73047757FAB" Guid="0A1AE820-0FF7-442C-8333-9FEFA2E3F33C">
    <File Id="_CA463C5C_E397_40E6_9B7B_28CCA647D0CA" Name="BCGCBPRO2440d120.dll" Source="..\workspace\Debug\BCGCBPRO2440d120.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
  <Directory Id="dir_350BD3EA_2F6C_4AD4_A960_8AB2C40F4F36" Name="Docs">
    <Component Id="DocFolderId" Guid="32DAE480-7C01-4BAA-B99D-9FE8D7D43369" MultiInstance="yes">         
      <CreateFolder />
    </Component>
    <Component Id="comp_FFFDE3FE_1205_4E74_82B1_E832501A096C" Guid="EECC223C-EBAD-43CA-9F3C-4A19FD9E7429">
      <File Id="_D0FE1868_D0D7_4778_8BC6_D40FE2B21DB2" Name="ModuleList(1).txt" Source="..\ModuleList(1).txt" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Id="comp_07E32598_CA8D_46B6_A3D6_DA36FD308E1F" Guid="FCCC41AA-17BC-4ADA-925D-631A614C9F80">
      <File Id="_894CFDFB_4514_4CAC_86C3_426CC6836B7C" Name="ModuleList(2).txt" Source="..\ModuleList(2).txt" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Id="comp_21465088_A65C_43D4_A038_93412404BA91" Guid="67D18D29-6466-4D36-A279-A9396A62019C">
      <File Id="_C9362477_88D8_463C_B77D_7097255F5E13" Name="ModuleList.txt" Source="..\ModuleList.txt" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Id="comp_3C85BB37_5715_45E7_A135_C640D7348360" Guid="6DDB0F88-7346-4221-8FB1-106C5F707EE5">
      <File Id="_BFE55263_BD18_427B_9F87_30403BB2540D" Name="ReadMe.txt" Source="..\ReadMe.txt" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: in this particular example, you don't need the components with `<CreateFolder/>` inside. As long as there are other components with files, the parent directory for that will be created. So, you can try to remove that and see what happens. And BTW, are there any warnings when you compile/link your MSI?

Comment: When installing multiple installs on the same machine during the authoring of your installer you can get into situations where you have phantom component references or fake installs. You should have run with `/l*v log.txt` to see if some components were referenced by multiple installs. Also if you have conditional features that are by default not installed, this can cause issues if you don't put "or Installed" in the condition enabling that feature does not get satisfied during uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

You used `KeyPath="yes"` in all of your components. This means, that such a component is used as a checkpoint for the Windows installer, for example if you want to repair an installation. It means that it is **a mandatory component** required for the application to function.

Since you are using multiple instances, and you mentioned you installed more than just the default instance, the Windows installer **does not remove key components until the last one of the instances is getting uninstalled** (i.e. it keeps track of them internally with a reference counter).

Answer (score 0):

Use `MultiInstance="yes"` for each and every component, and like Yan says, get rid of the `<CreateFolder/>` component